# Why does estimability imply identifiability?

Tags: identifiability, estimability

Let $P_{\theta}$ be the distribution (known up to a parameter $\theta$ in parameter space $\Theta$) of a random variable.
A parameter (function) $\gamma=g\left(\theta\right)$ is called identifiable if and only if $$\forall\,\theta,\theta^{*}\in\Theta:P_{\theta}=P_{\theta^{*}}\Rightarrow g\left(\theta\right)=g\left(\theta^{*}\right).$$

A parameter (function) $\gamma=g\left(\theta\right)$ is called estimable if and only if $$\exists\,\hat{\gamma}:\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left[\hat{\gamma}\right]=g\left(\theta\right)\:\forall\,\theta\in\Theta,$$
where $\hat{\gamma}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\gamma$.

Why does estimability imply identifiability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-identifiability means that
$$\exists \theta, \theta^*:\ g(\theta)\neq g(\theta^*),\ P_\theta=P_{\theta^*}.
$$
But then it is impossible to have $\hat \gamma$ with $E_{\theta}(\hat\gamma)=g(\theta)\ \forall \theta$, because if $P_\theta=P_{\theta^*}$ then $E_{\theta}(\hat\gamma)=E_{\theta^*}(\hat\gamma)$ but $g(\theta)\neq g(\theta^*)$.

Comment: +1 didn't think about the contrapositive. The proof might be slightly more obvious when you would explicitly state "... impossible to have $\hat{\gamma}$ with $E_{\theta}(\hat{\gamma})=g(\theta)\ \forall\theta$ (including $\theta^{*}$), ...". Now that the statement has been proven, can you provide an intuition why it is true?

Comment: Not sure how "intuitive" you'll find this, but non-identifiability means that you can't tell $g(\theta)$ and $g(\theta^*)$ apart, as the distribution parametrized by them is the same. But if this is so, you can't have an estimator that can tell one from the other either; how could you? There's no difference in the data that you will observe from one or the other. Well, this is just said in words what the proof says...

Comment: Yes, I see this "intuition" (as you said, it's just the proof in words) when looking at the contrapositive statement. I was looking for something similar for the original statement (which is, of course, equivalent). But the "contrapositive perspective" might be the easiest way to understand it.